# How do I display an error message if a file is not found?

Tags: java, file, error-handling, message

I wrote a program to read from a specific file and was wondering how would I display a custom message if that file were to not be found. What I have currently does not work, could someone explain why?

```
try {
       //create the file writer
       Fwrite = new FileWriter(file);
       Fwrite.write("Student Name \t\t\t Test Score \t Grade\n");
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           Fwrite.write(students[i].getStudentLName() + ", " + students[i].getStudentFName() + 
                   " \t\t\t "+ students[i].getTestScore() + " \t\t  " + students[i].getGrade() + "\n");
       }
       Fwrite.write("\n\nHighest Test Score: " + highestScore + "\n");

       Fwrite.write("Students having the highest test score\n");

       //writes the test scores in descending order
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           if (students[i].getTestScore() == highestScore) {
               Fwrite.write(students[i].getStudentLName() + ", ");
               Fwrite.write(students[i].getStudentFName() + "\n");
           }
       }

   //catches any errors
   } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("File mot Found!");
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   //try catch method to catch any errors
   System.out.println("File Complete!");
   //close file
   Fwrite.close();
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Why do you think its not working? Are you not getting "File mot Found" message?

Comment: Um, the code here is _writing_ to a file, not reading.  It's not an error to _write_ to a non-existent file; if the file didn't exist before, it will be created.

Comment: The error I keep getting is: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Data.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Define "does not work".

Answer (score 0):

To show file not found exception change catch block to this

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception will be thrown by the FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, and RandomAccessFile constructors when a file with the specified pathname does not exist. It will also be thrown by these constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible, for example when an attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing.

CHECK THIS Link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html